# how do I display document-uri as text in an html document from a xslt file in internet explorer?

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xslt, internet-explorer-9, xslt-2.0

I have the following two files. When I try to view the xml document in internet explorer 9 it does not translate using the xslt file.

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl.xslt"?>
<foo>
  <bar>baz</bar>
</foo>
```

my xslt file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
>
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="/foo/bar"/>
        </title>
      </head>
      <body>

        <!-- It works if i remove the following xsl:value-of tag -->

        <xsl:value-of select="document-uri()"/>
        <div style="color: #ff0000;">
          <xsl:value-of select="/foo/bar/text()"/>
        </div>
        <div style="color: #ff0000;">RED</div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I remove the `<xsl:value-of select="document-uri()"/>` tag the xml is properly translated.
I have tried the following usages of document-uri:

- document-uri()
- document-uri('/')
- document-uri('/foo')
- document-uri('foo')
- fn:document-uri()
- fn:document-uri('/')
- fn:document-uri('/foo')
- fn:ocument-uri('foo')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`document-uri()` is an XPath 2.0 function -- not an XPath 1.0 one.**

Internat Explorer uses internally MSXML, which is an XSLT 1.0 only processor and doesn't know about XPath 2.0.

Therefore, you are out of luck.

Just for information -- at present none of the 5 major browsers implement XSLT 2.0.

If you want to use XSLT 2.0 in the browser, you could do so with **[Saxon CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml)**.

**Recently Michael Kay announced that the next version of Saxon CE will be fully open source -- and it is available now**.